# Copy 2 cells and paste do a different sheet once combobox has changed

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a workbook where a user can add information I.E Username and password.

Sheet2 is where all the data is store. I use column's A, B AND C.

I have a combobox on my UserForm. The raw source for my combobox is Column A. When a user selects one of the options from the combobox i want it to copy the values from Column B & C and paste the values into another worksheet. This is what i have so far:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$3").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
Range("B2:C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Displaypage").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Database").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$3").AutoFilter Field:=1
Range("A2").Select
```

But when i run this i get Autofilter method of range class failed

Has anyone got an other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your combobox is populated by the RowSource property, give this a try:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim cbo As ComboBox
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range

    Set cbo = Me.ComboBox1
    Set wsDest = Sheets("Displaypage")
    Set rngData = Range(cbo.RowSource)

    wsDest.Range("A1:B1").ClearContents 'Remove previous data (if any)
    If cbo.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub 'Nothing selected

    rngData.Cells(1).Offset(cbo.ListIndex, 1).Resize(, 2).Copy wsDest.Range("A1")

End Sub
```